# Installing webpacker in legacy Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack-4, webpacker

I've added the webpacker gem, bundled, installed and edited all my javascript_include tags to javascript_pack.

What happens with the existing javascript? I have lots of it under app/assets/javascripts and vendor/assets/javascripts. It doesn't seem to pick it up automatically.

Some of this javascript is required into application.js.erb and some other files load directly into various parts of the application, eg:

```
app/assets/javascripts/application.js.erb # linked to from application layout
//= require global
//= require bootstrap
//= require moment
//= require websockets
//= require init
```

Then I also have:

```
app/assets/javascripts/users.js
//= require table
//= require form
//= require sync
//= require controllers/users/index
```

Some of these files are small Vue apps, I've placed their templates under Rails views. Now after this webpacker business I have app/assets/javascripts (which contains all my actual code but is ignored), then app/javascript which I don't know what it is, and app/javascripts where I'm supposed to put my Vue apps. Or the other way around. Or something.

How do I get all this to work with webpacker? None of the tutorials I've found cover migrating existing code to webpacker and to be honest I don't understand much from all those javascript snippets they just dump there but don't explain what it actually does and how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, adding webpack doesn't change anything. For example, if you leave `javascript_include_tag 'application'` in your layout, it will continue to work the same as it did before adding webpack.

The files in the `javascript/packs` folder are entry points for javascript. If you are doing a single page app, you will likely have a single pack like `application.js` which boots up your entire application. If you are doing a conventional app, you will likely have a main `application.js` file that loads all global scripts, plus other page or component level scripts like `settings.js` or `calendar.js`. These scripts are loaded with `javascript_pack_tag 'application'`.

If you move your files out of the assets folder into the javascript folder you can then add them to your pack file like so:

```js
import 'global';
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
import 'bootstrap';
import 'moment';
import 'websockets';

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    console.log('do init stuff here');
    // use bootstrap here
});
```

Comment: Seems like I have to specify the path for each file using either import or require but even after I do that it throws errors, eg after importing bootstrap it complains about jquery not being found :( this is a horrible mechanism :( also no way to require gem JS

Comment: If you are running into an issue with global jQuery access you can assign it to the window manually. I've updated the answer to reflect that. If you are still getting an error, add it to the question and I'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. Seems we're not going to be using webpacker, it complicates things a lot for us. The Rails asset pipeline isn't ideal either but at least it works out of the box without much effort.